# WSO2 - IS - Synchronize Users from WSO2 to a Service Provider

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to create a user in Wso2 (version 5.8) Identity Server and then populate it into my Service Providers automatically.

At this moment, after user registration in my Wso2, then I need to register the same user manually in each Service Providers (in my case, a SP is M-Files tool which provides a way to create user described [here](https://www.m-files.com/user-guide/latest/eng/How_can_I_add_a_new_user_to_the_document_vault.html))

I am not sure if wso2 offers an automatic way to do this. I read the following documentation

- [Inbound provisioning](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Inbound+Provisioning): This approach is used for the opposite goal. Create a user in a Service Provider and with SCIM API I can create it into my wso2.
- [Outbound provisioning](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Outbound+Provisioning): This approach is very close that I want to but require relating the Service Provider with an Identity Provider (which must implement SCIM) and I dont want to use my Service Provider as an Identity Provider.
- User store: I think it is not what I looking for. I think wso2 queries the external user store searching if the user which attempt to login is valid or not. I dont want my Service Provider act like a Identity Provider

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Outbound provisioning: This approach is very close that I want to but require relating the Service Provider with an Identity Provider (which must implement SCIM) and I dont want to use my Service Provider as an Identity Provider.

This is the approach you should be using. You don't have to **use** it as an Identity Provider. Just **register** it as an Identity Provider so that WSO2 can provision users to M-Files.

Regarding provisioning to M-Files, WSO2 support standard user management SCIM2 rest APIs. But if (I couldn't find any reference) M-files doesn't support such, you might have to find the API format that M-files support and then you can write a simple Java extension (Custom outbound provisioning Connector) to WSO2 Identity Server, so that it can provision users to M-files in a way that it prefers.

[Documentation for customization](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-an-outbound-provisioning-connector/)